# Custom .sty warning on specific command

Tags: macros, errors, warnings, package-writing

I am writing a custom `.sty` file and I notice that it can break if a certain command, native in Latex, is called.

I would like to throw a warning to the user and say "Don't use this command!".
I know the warning can be send as follow:

`\PackageWarningNoLine{myClass}{Don't use this command!}`

How do I check for whether the command has been used?

Comment: It can't be a well defined package if it breaks with a native command of LaTeX. I think you should provide more information so that we can help you to improve the package. I know it's not a good idea, however you can redefine the certain command like `\def\foobar{\PackageWarning`

Comment: Okay, break is a big word. It's the `beamer` package for presentation and the command `\subsection{}` will create a new line in the top.

I want a background image which fit the top border, so by NOT using `\subsection` I avoid having to scale the image I insert.

Answer (score 2):

In your package use

```
\newcommand\subsection[2][]{%
\PackageWarningNoLine{myClass}{Don't use this command!}}
```